# Why Array.forEach() is not blocking the middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I know that Array.forEach is synchronous.

But I've this code:

```
function middleware (req, res, next) {
  Array.forEach(
    Array.forEach(
      if(true) { return next(); }
    )
  )

  return res.send("false");
}

// next()
function isTrue (req, res) {
  return res.send("true");
}
```

And every time I execute it, it sends two headers. First the isTrue function header, and later, the middleware function header.

I understand that if `Array.forEach()` is synchronous, it should be executed before `res.send("false")`. But it's not the behaviour. So there is something that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the complete question we'd need to see your code, but to answer the very basic javascript question, the `return` inside `forEach` only returns from `forEach` and not from your outer middleware function. So everything within the middleware function is still executing after `forEach`.

Again, it's impossible to offer a real solution, but instead of `forEach` you'd typically use some for these kind of checks.

```
const ret = [1,2,3].some(e => e === '<yourCondition>');
res.send(ret);
```